# Select box option getting scrollbar only in chrome

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular 5 in my project and bootstrap for CSS. I have a select box where I am loading options dynamically from a service. After loading the options they are coming with a scrollbar.

[image]

This is happening only for the first. once the data is loaded it is working normally.

Code:-

```
<select #selectedUser autofocus name='username' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='username' required>
  <option value="">--Select UserGroup Name--</option>
  <option value="" *ngIf="!loadingUserGroups">Loading</option>
  <ng-container *ngIf="loadingUserGroups">
      <option *ngFor="let user of dropdownListUsers; let i=index" [value]="user.userGroupid">{{user.name}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>


loadUsersDDL(resultsUsers) {
        this.loadingUserGroups = true;
            this.dropdownListUsers = [];
            resultsUsers.forEach(eachObj => {
                this.dropdownListUsers.push({
                    userGroupid: eachObj.principalid,
                    name: eachObj.name
                });
            });
    }
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: share us your html and componen.ts code

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue in stackblitz, but unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce it.

Comment: that's fine can you share your code here.

Comment: @BearNithi added html and ts. For loadUserDDl() method I am getting the data from a service.